# how can we read the key and value pair from pdf using python , if data present with space

Tags: python, pdf, automation, key, unique-values

example file

[image]

how to read the key and values if data separated with space?

expecting values  like
Apartment[1212,331] , City=['','']
or
[column name ]
[values

Comment: I'm quite sure there's both articles and questions here regarding parsing PDF. Did you try any of them? If not, that's where you should start. If you did, then include more details into your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import re

# creating a pdf reader object
# from Test_Config.practice import pdf
aa={}
reader = PdfReader('C:\GDPR_Automation\TestInput_Files\Freport.pdf')
print(len(reader.pages))
for page in reader.pages:
    # count= count+1
    text = page.extract_text()
    # ocr_text = page.getContents().extractText()
    s= text.replace(' ','')
    print (s)

Comment: can any one  help